# Time triggered script to paste value if condition is met (absence of #N/A)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, automation, google-sheets, conditional-statements

**Here's the idea**: I want to automate the data entry from one cell that changes constantly to a range in another sheet, so the script fires at specific times based on a timed trigger, copies the value of the changing cell and fills a column in another sheet with the value of the changing cell. I should mention the reason I use a timed trigger is because I do not want to have the Spreadsheet opened at all times on a computer but rather have it happen automatically without me opening it.

**Here's the Problem**: Because the changing cells is based on Google/Yahoo Finance data, it can take time to load once the Spreadsheet is opened. Typically the cells will read "Loading" for a few seconds until the data is downloaded. During this time, the cells I'm looking to copy and paste read either "Loading" or "#N/A". As a result these are the "values" copied and pasted into my recorded data sheet. Sometimes the data isn't downloaded at all and the cells reads "#N/A" until I reload the Spreadsheet.

**Here's my progress so far:** So far my script is mostly functional, if the timed trigger is set to a short period (5 minutes) the results are perfect and all the data is recorded correctly, however I'm looking into this script running once or twice a day and when I increase the time to hours some data appears as "#N/A" or "Loading". Sometimes reloading the Spreadsheet solves this.

I get the impression that Google Sheets doesn't keep the data cached for more than a few minutes, so when the time between triggers is short the data is still available and everything works, but when the time is increased (for example to 1 hour) everything is re-downloaded, resulting in the "Loading".

**Here's the code script I'm using to copy/paste the values from one sheet to another:**

```
function PasteValue() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet ID");
var nextRow = ss.getSheetByName('My recorded data sheet').getLastRow()+1;
ss.getRange("Changing Data Sheet!F6").copyTo(ss.getRange("My recorded data sheet!A" + nextRow),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

**My idea:** The solution I'm thinking about is to have a second function before the "PasteValue()" one which would reload the spreadsheet until no "#N/A" can be found in the "Changing Data Sheet". This would be done by timed trigger as well so:

- at constant interval the spreadsheet is opened
- the data sheet is searched for "#N/A"
- if one #N/A is found the spreadsheet is reloaded until none can be
  found
- if no #N/As can be found, the values are copy/pasted in the recorded
  data sheet

I found a script that reloads the spreadsheet until no more #N/As are found, however when I combine my script and the following one I still get missing data on my recorded data sheet.

The [refresh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614895/cells-containing-custom-functions-return-nan-when-spreadsheet-is-not-open-a/17371490#17371490][1]) I found on Stack Overflow:

```
function refreshSheet(spreadsheet, sheet) {
var dataArrayRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
var dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues(); // necessary to refresh custom functions
var nanFound = true;
while(nanFound) {
for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  if(dataArray[i].indexOf('#N/A') >= 0) {
    nanFound = true;
    dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues();
    break;
  } // end if
  else if(i == dataArray.length - 1) nanFound = false;
 } // end for
} // end while
}
```

Am I not getting something?
Is there an easier way, or is this not possible?

Comment: I'm wondering about the fact that you mention that refreshing the spreadsheet only resolves this 'some' of the time. Perhaps the issue is that refreshing the sheet isn't solving the loading errors, and the sheet continues to refresh. Have you considered using one timed trigger to refresh the sheet, and a second timed trigger that runs a bit later to process the sheet? It might give it plenty of time to 'load' then.

Comment: @HDCerberus Thanks for the reply! Yeah I did consider that by using "clock triggers" and setting a specific time for both. However from what I've read on the Google Apps Script website (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) the time triggers are executed +-15 minutes regardless of the value you put in, and at 15 minute intervals I'm already seeing some N/A appearing

Comment: @HDCerberus So I tried to create two scripts which execute at different times and let it run over the course of a day, unfortunately missing data has indeed been recorded which confirms what I feared would happen. I'm wondering if maybe my refresh script isn't correct, but I'm not sure how to test it.