# Google finance 200 day moving average is getting as #NA in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I'm calculating Google finance 200 day moving average formula in google sheet using formula

**=average(query(sort(GoogleFinance("GOOG","price", TODAY()-320, TODAY()),1,0),"select Col2 limit 200"))**

Then in google app script I'm getting the above cell value in variable as below

**var val = sheet.getRange("T101").getValue();**

but in google script I'm getting that variable value as **#NA**. Can anyone please advise what is causing the issue?

Comment: Based from this [blog](http://www.gadgetsappshacks.com/2013/08/how-to-automatically-record-daily.html), be noted that `GoogleFinance()` only executes when the spreadsheet is open. So when your trigger runs unattended, the values will not be set. The sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371490/5832311) may help to keep refreshing the sheet (using `.getValues()`) until all of the #N/A's disappear. It works but does add a small lag.

Comment: I used the logic mentioned in thread as below data = sheet.getRange("B106").getValue(); // necessary to refresh custom functions
  var nanFound = true;
  while(nanFound) {
      if(data.indexOf('#N/A') >= 0) {
        nanFound = true;
        data = sheet.getRange("B106").getValue();
      } // end if
      else nanFound = false;
  } // end while


but it is running for infinite time and #NA is not getting changed to value

Comment: This is expected behavior for historical Google Finance use when accessed via script.

Answer (score 16):

To expand on @Ric ky's answer, the trick here is to get to a range so the average math can be performed on it.

For this working answer:

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(GoogleFinance("GOOG","all",WORKDAY(TODAY(),-200),TODAY()),,3))`

Here's why it works:

`=AVERAGE(
    INDEX( // used to get 1 value or a range of values from a reference
        GoogleFinance("GOOG","all",WORKDAY(TODAY(),-200),TODAY()), // returns an expanded array with column headers, used by INDEX as the reference
        , // bypass INDEX's row argument to return an entire column to be AVERAGE'd
        3 // we want the High column with an index of 3; index is 1-based
    )
)`

A visual:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX( GoogleFinance( "GOOG", "all" , WORKDAY( TODAY(), -200 ) , TODAY() ) , , 3))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's usually better to provide an explanation of why and how this code helps in this case. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)